# Enumerating hash based collections

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hash, collections

As much as I have read and understood, the Dictionary internally uses hashing to hash a key to some memory location(called bucket) and stores the value in a LinkedList over there. If some another key is hashed to the same location, it is probably appended to that linkedlist.

I am pretty sure there are enough buckets to make the insertions and removals in the dictionary fast enough but besides that there is also some housekeeping going on. Every time a key is added to the dictionary, the Dictionary.Keys and Dictionary.Values properties are also updated. I wanted to understand the complexity of that.

How does the foreach loop ennumerate through all the keys or values in a dictionary. I tried to Google the answer but didn't really reach a concrete answer. My research comes down to answering this question - "How has Microsoft probably implemented the KeyCollection class or even ValueCollection class for that matter?"

It might be using a List(essentially an array) or LinkedList underneath. But then, removing a key from the dictionary would cause inefficient housekeeping, isn't it?

There is a similar situation in HashSet also. The elements are inserted in a random fashion based on some hash code. How is foreach enumerating every element when there is no order or no links from one element to another?

Can someone please give me an insight?

Comment: Why are you trying to enumerate a dictionary? Is this just to get an understanding of dictionaries or are you actually trying to do it  - don't :-)?

Comment: Its mostly for understanding purposes. Not enumerating a dictionary or keys or values but we can do that using foreach loop. I am just trying to understand how foreach does it under the hood.

Comment: [Source code talks more than anything](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs)